# Regex to find substring between two substrings

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I have looked at other answers, but can't seem to match them to my code. I have strings containing something like this:

```
"x": {"field": "Horsepower","type": "quantitative"},
"y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon","type": "quantitative"}
```

and I want to be able to replace so it looks like:

```
"x": {"field": "...","type": "quantitative"},
"y": {"field": "...","type": "quantitative"},
```

So I am using `str.replace(/regex here/, '...')`

I think I want to find what is between `"field": "` and `",`.
I could also do it by finding the string beginning with `"field": "` and ending with `",` and use

`str.replace(/regex here/, '"field": "...",')`

What do I put for the regex?
Also, explanation behind the regex would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Parse the JSON, alter the structures, and re-encode as JSON.

Comment: @meagar what does that look like

Comment: I would prefer the answer posted by meagar.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is the **wrong** tool for this job. The string appears to be JSON, so parse it, and modify the parsed data structures, and then re-encode as JSON.

```js
var str = '{ "x": {"field": "Horsepower","type": "quantitative"}, "y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon","type": "quantitative"}}';

var data = JSON.parse(str);

data.x.field = '...';
data.y.field = '...';

str = JSON.stringify(data);

document.write(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Pattern `(\{"[^"]+":\s*")[^"]*` and replace with `\1...` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZelRPw/1)

```
(           # Capturing Group (1)
  \{        # "{"
  "         # """
  [^"]      # Character not in ["] Character Class
  +         # (one or more)(greedy)
  ":        # "":"
  \s        # <whitespace character>
  *         # (zero or more)(greedy)
  "         # """
)           # End of Capturing Group (1)
[^"]        # Character not in ["] Character Class
*           # (zero or more)(greedy)
```

Edit: if the presence of 'field' is a must, use `(\{"field":\s*")[^"]*` instead.

Comment: This is a ticking time-bomb. This blindly replaces the first value it finds, rather than correctly replacing the value of the `field` property.

Comment: @meagar, it is based on what the op posted, and it is very easily adaptable to limit to just "field"     `(\{"field":\s*")[^"]*`